# Best practices: .NET: How to return PK against an oracle database?

Tags: .net, oracle

With SQLServer, it seems to be generally accepted that adding a SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() to the end of your insert is the best way to return the PK of the newly-inserted record, assuming you're using an auto-increment field for the pk.

However, I can't seem to find the equivalent for Oracle.

Best practice seems to be to use a sequence to generate the PK, but there are different options for how to implement even that. Do you leave it up to the developer to insert sequence.nexval, or use a trigger?

In either case, getting the new ID back seems to be a common problem.

Suggestions and solutions I've run across include:

- creating a stored proc that returns the PK
- running a select id from seq.nextval, then passing that to the insert
- select max(id) after insert (Note: Don't do this!)
- add a RETURNING clause to the insert

What should the "best practice" solution be for this situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the RETURNING clause to do this in Oracle stored procs.

For example:

TABLEA has NAME and EMP_ID.  EMP_ID is populated internally when records are inserted.

INSERT INTO TABLEA(NAME) VALUES ('BOB') RETURNING EMP_ID INTO o_EMP_ID;

That's assuming that line is in a stored proc with an output parameter of o_EMP_ID.

Hope that helps... if not, here's a more detailed example:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm

Comment: Thanks for noting that, I've changed the link to something more stable (if a little less friendly - the Oracle docs on the RETURNING clause)

Answer (score 4):

The RETURNING clause is intended for just this kind of usage, so I would call it a best practice to use it.

An alternative would be to select seq.CURRVAL after the insert.  That returns the last value obtained from the sequence by **this** session.

Comment: But be careful in case a concurrent call has incremented the sequence, right?

Comment: No, CURRVAL is the last value obtained from the sequence by THIS session.

Comment: With Java: Select the sequence.nextval before the insert, and set the value in your SQL statement and don't use a trigger on the table before an insert. This is because in Java RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS isn't implemented on PreparedStatement for the Oracle JDBC driver.

Comment: Just don't make the newbie mistake I did and use the same database connection in multiple threads, because then CURRVAL could give you the wrong result.

Answer (score 2):

The stored procedure and the returning clause have the distinct benefit of a single database call any other solution is inferior.  Whether you do it via a stored procedure or you use a returning clause is a whole can of worms in itself.