# Returning in Oracle INSERT is not returning proper value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, insert

I have an ASP.NET web application (VB.NET) using an Oracle database.  On an insert, I need to get the identity of the inserted row back.  I am trying to use RETURNING, but I keep getting a value of 1 returned.

```
Dim strInsert As String = "INSERT INTO L.TRANSACTIONS (LOCATION_KEY, TRANS_CREATOR, TRANS_EMAIL, TRANS_PHONE) VALUES (:location_key, :trans_creator, :trans_email, :trans_phone) RETURNING TRANS_ID INTO :ukey"

Try
    If oConn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
        oConn.Open()
    End If

    Dim oCmnd As New OracleCommand(strInsert, oConn)
    oCmnd.Parameters.Add("location_key", Session.Item("location").ToString.Trim())
    oCmnd.Parameters.Add("trans_creator", Session.Item("userID").ToString.Trim())
    oCmnd.Parameters.Add("trans_email", Session.Item("mail").ToString.Trim())
    oCmnd.Parameters.Add("trans_phone", Session.Item("phone").ToString.Trim())
    oCmnd.Parameters.Add("ukey", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2, System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue)

    Dim strUkey As String = oCmnd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

When I run the application, the record gets inserted and the TRANS_ID is incrementing but the returned value is always "1".

Comment: is it a datatype issue?  try making ukey an int

Comment: @jle - No.  Changing to an int16, it still returns a value of 1.  I'm wondering if it is returning a Boolean of true as an int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the result of `ExecuteNonQuery` to the variable, rather than getting the value assigned to the parameter you've created. I believe you want to change the last line to something like this (untested):

```
oCmnd.ExecuteNonQuery
Dim strUkey As String = oCmnd.Parameters.GetParameter("ukey").Value
```

Comment: A combination of this and jle's comment above.  I tried changing the datatype of my VB ukey variable, not the parameter.  So once it was the correct Oracle datatype I could get the value I needed.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `ExecuteNonQuery` will return the number of rows affected:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. For CREATE TABLE and DROP
>   TABLE statements, the return value is 0. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1.

You can see that exist another question that covers the practices for doing it:

[Best practices: .NET: How to return PK against an oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158571/best-practices-net-how-to-return-pk-against-an-oracle-database)

Comment: I read that question before posting but it didn't show how to get the return value with an OracleCommand.  Thanks for the heads up on the ExecuteNonQuery.  For SQL Server (which I am more familiar with) I just use ExecuteScalar with SCOPE_IDENTITY but ExecuteScalar in this case returns Nothing.

Comment: In that question they said to use a stored procedure that returns the id of the inserted record.