# Oracle: "sequence ID_TABLE1.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session" - how can I obtain last values of sequence?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I'm doing 2 INSERT statements in Oracle DB. 1st INSERT is saved allways when my certain textbox is not empty on form. 2nd INSERT is being saved only If Datagridview 1st cell is not empty. These tables are joins via ID_Table1, and I use ID_Table1_seq to automatically generate new autonumber. When I try to save 2nd INSERT I get error:  "sequence ID_Table1.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session". 1st INSERT allways completes. I tried using "ID_Table1.nextval -1" for 2nd INSERT, but then problem occurs IF datagridview has more records to save - a new sequence number generates. Can somebody tell me how to obtain sequence current value?. Here is my snapshot of what I tried:

```
    Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click

     OracleConn()'I call this function for connecting to DB

     Using cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand()
           cmd.Connection = OracleConn()
           '/////////I'm adding plenty parameters here/////////
           cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (ID_Table1, Field1, Field2)
           VALUES(ID_Table1_seq.nextval,: Field1Parameter,: Field2Parameter)" 

        'When Textbox is not empty Execute 1st INSERT and check Datagrid for 2nd INSERT
      If Not MyTxt.Text = "" Then
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
         cmd.CommandText="select last_number from user_sequences where sequence_name='ID_TABLE1_SEQ'"
           For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
               If row.Cells(0).Value <> Nothing Then

                         '//////Adding plenty parameters here too/////////
                         cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table2 (ID_Table2, ID_Table1, Field1, Field2) 
                         VALUES (ID_TABLE2_seq.nextval, ID_Table1_seq.currval,: Field1Parameter,: Field2Parameter)"
                         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End Using
                Else 'If Datagridview 1st cell empty 
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
             MsgBox("Saved successfully.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
       Else
         Exit Sub            
       End If
     End Using

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved It, finally. I needed to clear all parameters right after any execution. I also combined both queries in same connection :

```
Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click

     OracleConn()'I call this function for connecting to DB

     Using cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand()
           cmd.Connection = OracleConn()
           '/////////I'm adding plenty parameters here/////////
           cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (ID_Table1, Field1, Field2)
           VALUES(ID_Table1_seq.nextval,: Field1Parameter,: Field2Parameter)" 

        'When Textbox is not empty Execute 1st INSERT and check Datagrid for 2nd INSERT
      If Not MyTxt.Text = "" Then
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
         cmd.Parameters.Clear()
           For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
               If row.Cells(0).Value <> Nothing Then

                         '//////Adding plenty parameters here too/////////
                         cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table2 (ID_Table2, ID_Table1, Field1, Field2) 
                         VALUES (ID_TABLE2_seq.nextval, ID_Table1_seq.currval,: Field1Parameter,: Field2Parameter)"
                         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                         cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                    End Using
                Else 'If Datagridview 1st cell empty 
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
             MsgBox("Saved successfully.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
       Else
         Exit Sub            
       End If
     End Using

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You create 2 different connections:

First

```
cmd.Connection = OracleConn()
       '/////////I'm adding plenty parameters here/////////
       cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (ID_Table1, Field1, Field2)
       VALUES(ID_Table1_seq.nextval,: Field1Parameter,: Field2Parameter)"
```

Second

```
                     cmd1.Connection = OracleConn()
                     '//////Adding plenty parameters here too/////////
```

And of course in second connection no one call

```
ID_Table1_seq.next_val
```

Edited:

```
   cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (ID_Table1, Field1, Field2)
           VALUES(ID_Table1_seq.nextval,: Field1Parameter,: Field2Parameter);"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()  // This executes your query

// Set new sql query
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID_Table1_seq.currval from dual;"
Dim currentID as Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()  // I don't know syntax in vb.net. Just search
```

Comment: thanks for response. I know that, and why I can't use sequence.currval. But how can I obtain current value of "ID_Table1_seq.next_val" from 1st statement ?. If I use "ID_Table1_seq.next_val" then sequence just generates new numbers, which doesnt join tables.

Comment: Why do you need several time open connection? Use just one connection per this business rule. For simple view you create a lot of connections. It opens opportunity to potential attack to your db.

Comment: How ? If datagrid rows would be empty, then record for 2nd statement would be inserted too -  "ID_Table1".

Comment: It depends on how many times 'row.Cells(0).Value <> Nothing' is true. And I ask you again why do you need several time open connection? To your question how get "ID_Table1_seq.next_val" - in first connect read ID_Table1_seq.cur_val through new query in the same connection.

Comment: I'm not sure If I quite follow you. I'm trying to put both queries in same OracleCommand now, is that what you meant ? I get more errors now though.

Comment: Put 'select ID_Table1_seq.curval from dual' in the new command in the same connection(first connection)

Comment: I don't know how to put that together. Check my edited question INSERT string - I tried what you said, but I get "invalid character" or "statement not properly ended" error.

Comment: I change answer. Take a look

Comment: I still get same error as before - "Sequence ID_Table1.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session". Looks like both queries must be in same command, but then how can I perform loop for datagrid ?

Comment: Then your OracleConn automatically close session. Try approach from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727051/returning-in-oracle-insert-is-not-returning-proper-value

Comment: I tried that too, but ".Parameters.GetParameter" isn't available in VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this query:

```
select last_number from all_sequences where sequence_owner=user and sequence_name='ID_TABLE1_SEQ'
```

or

```
select last_number from user_sequences where sequence_name='ID_TABLE1_SEQ'
```

**Edited:**
But if you have more than 1 session you can get logic error, for example:

1. session 1 execute NEXTVAL
2. session 2 execute NEXTVAL
3. session 1 select CURRVAL and it will gets ID from session 2...

The right way is to use RETURNING INTO clause.

```
Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click

 OracleConn()'I call this function for connecting to DB

 Using cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand()
       cmd.Connection = OracleConn()
       '/////////I'm adding plenty parameters here///////// don't forget to add output parameter CurrID
       cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (ID_Table1, Field1, Field2)
       VALUES(ID_Table1_seq.nextval,: Field1Parameter,: Field2Parameter)
       RETURNING ID_Table1 INTO :CurrID" 

    'When Textbox is not empty Execute 1st INSERT and check Datagrid for 2nd INSERT
  If Not MyTxt.Text = "" Then
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

     '///////////get the value of the parameter CurrID
     CurrID = cmd.Parameters[2].value

       For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
           If row.Cells(0).Value <> Nothing Then

                     '//////Adding plenty parameters here too///////// don't forget to add parameter ID = CurrID
                     cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table2 (ID_Table2, ID_Table1, Field1, Field2) 
                     VALUES (ID_TABLE2_seq.nextval, :ID,: Field1Parameter,: Field2Parameter)"
                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            Else 'If Datagridview 1st cell empty 
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
         MsgBox("Saved successfully.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
   Else
     Exit Sub            
   End If
 End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried many options now, check my last edited question where I joined all queries in same connection plus your suggestion, but I get "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number" error.

Comment: Beside that, both queries you suggested doen't produce any results in Oracle DB. Only "Select ID_table_seq.currval from dual" works for me.

Comment: I solved It. Parameters were problem all the time I guess. Check my answer, If you care I'll mark your answer If you edit It. Thanks for all your help !!